# nodejs reuse the last TLS connect of same server

Tags: node.js, ssl

My node daemon connect to the **same** TLS server multiple times. I want to save the TLS connection time.

```
// repeat every 5 seconds
setInterval(() => {
    const socket = tls.connect(443, 'test.com')
    socket.on('connect', () => {
        socket.write(someUniqueData)
    })
}, 5000)
```

Is it possible to **reuse** the last TLS connection?

Answer (score 2):

You can save the socket easily enough, here's an example:

```
const tls = require('tls');
const someUniqueData = 'someUniqueData';

var savedSocket = null;

function getSocket() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        if (savedSocket) {
            console.log('getSocket: Reusing saved socket..');
            resolve(savedSocket);
            return;
        }

        console.log('getSocket: Creating new socket..');
        const socket = tls.connect(443, 'test.com');
        socket.on('connect', () => {
            console.log('Connected to host..');
            savedSocket = socket;
            resolve(savedSocket);
        });
        socket.on('error', (err) => {
            console.log('Error connecting to host..');
            reject(err);
        });     
    });
}

async function connectAndSend() {
    try {
        let socket = await getSocket();
        console.log('connectAndSend: Sending data..');
        socket.write(someUniqueData)
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('connectAndSend: Error occurred: ', err);
    }
}

// repeat every 5 seconds
setInterval(() => {
    connectAndSend();
}, 5000)
```